SwiftData Error with Relationships between three models
I am trying to get SwiftData to work with 3 models that are all interconnected. The simplified models and an example View that throws the error are attached below.
Creating a Company and an aircraft works fine, however, when trying to create a flight, the runtime error

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Illegal attempt to establish a relationship 'aircrafts' between objects in different contexts

is thrown. Does anyone know what I might do wrong?
This is the small example to show the problem:
The View with Buttons to trigger the creation of new instances, while the model context is injected in the app struct with .modelContainer(for: [Aircraft.self, Company.self, Flight.self]):
struct ContentView: View {
    @Query var flights: [Flight]
    @Query var aircrafts: [Aircraft]
    @Query var companies: [Company]
    
    @Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("\(companies.count) Companies")
            Text("\(aircrafts.count) Aircrafts")
            Text("\(flights.count) Flights")
            
            Button("Create Company") {
                let company = Company(name: "MyAirline", aircrafts: [], flights: [])
                modelContext.insert(company)
            }
            Button("Create Aircraft") {
                guard let company = companies.first else { return }
                let aircraft = Aircraft(company: company, flights: [])
                modelContext.insert(aircraft)
            }
            Button("Create Flight") {
                guard let company = companies.first,
                      let aircraft = aircrafts.first
                else { return }
                let flight = Flight(company: company, aircrafts: [aircraft])
                modelContext.insert(flight)
            }
            Button("Delete everything") {
                try? modelContext.delete(model: Flight.self)
                try? modelContext.delete(model: Aircraft.self)
                try? modelContext.delete(model: Company.self)
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

Here are the three models with their relationships:
@Model
final class Company {
    @Attribute(.unique) let name: String
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Aircraft.company)
    var aircrafts: [Aircraft]
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .cascade, inverse: \Flight.company)
    var flights: [Flight]
    
    init(name: String, aircrafts: [Aircraft], flights: [Flight]) {
        self.name = name
        self.aircrafts = aircrafts
        self.flights = flights
    }
}

@Model
final class Aircraft {
    var company: Company
    
    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \Flight.aircrafts)
    var flights: [Flight]
    
    init(company: Company, flights: [Flight]) {
        self.company = company
        self.flights = flights
    }
}

@Model
final class Flight {
    let company: Company
    let aircrafts: [Aircraft]
    
    init(company: Company, aircrafts: [Aircraft]) {
        self.company = company
        self.aircrafts = aircrafts
    }
}


I know this isn’t what the question is about but why do you need these three relationships, shouldn’t two be enough? What is a Flight in this context, is it like a route?

@JoakimDanielson Yes, exactly a flight route to which multiple aircraft can be assigned. Also an aircraft should be able to be assigned to different routes. So a many to many relationship.

Ok but why does Flight have a relationship to Company then? If all aircraft for a specific Flight object must belong to the same company isn’t that more of a business rule rather than a relationship, that is something you handle in your swift code before persisting the data?

It would be more flexible. For example, the Flight might still exist after all Aircraft were unassigned, to be reactivated later or for statistical reasons.

Maybe the problem is that a flight or route is something that several companies flies and that a single route has many departures each with a single aircraft. It’s your design but personally I would try to break up this relationship triangle you have right now.

I believe your many-to-many relationship between Aircraft and Flight is the problem. It is an odd setup, at least, to my eye. Certainly a plane can be scheduled for many different flights, but I would expect a flight to use exactly one airplane. The crash is because you have explicitly defined relationships that can't be achieved.
I modified Flight to make it 1-many with Aircraft and was able to create flights:
@Model
final class Flight {
    let company: Company
    let aircraft: Aircraft
    
    init(company: Company, aircraft: Aircraft) {
        self.company = company
        self.aircraft = aircraft
    }
}

But it's still not possible to delete a flight or aircraft.
When I tested the code, the "Delete everything" button failed with this console message:
error: Unhandled opt lock error from executeBatchDeleteRequest Constraint trigger violation: Batch delete failed due to mandatory OTO nullify inverse on Aircraft/company and userInfo {
NSExceptionOmitCallstacks = 1;
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Constraint trigger violation: Batch delete failed due to mandatory OTO nullify inverse on Aircraft/company";
"_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingFailureConflictsKey" =     (
);
}
CoreData: error: Unhandled opt lock error from executeBatchDeleteRequest Constraint trigger violation: Batch delete failed due to mandatory OTO nullify inverse on Aircraft/company and userInfo {
NSExceptionOmitCallstacks = 1;
NSLocalizedFailureReason = "Constraint trigger violation: Batch delete failed due to mandatory OTO nullify inverse on Aircraft/company";
"_NSCoreDataOptimisticLockingFailureConflictsKey" =     (
);
}

I removed the explicit @Relationship macros and allowed SwiftData to infer the relationships instead. That worked smoothly, except that you can now be left with zombie flights and aircraft when deleting a Company. So there's still some work to be done here with figuring out your relationships and delete rules.

Hi Hal, thanks for your answer. Yes, the many-to-many relationship might be the issue, but is it really that uncommon. In my case Flight means more like Route (Like a flightnumber), on which different Aircraft can be used, while an Aircraft also can be used on different routes. I could get around it I guess, but it seems odd to me that it is not working.
Assigning the aircrafts after the initialisation of Flight like @GoksuBayy suggested actually worked, however the deletion then threw an error.

Using inferred (rather than explicit) relationships if you can, and optional properties where appropriate, will save you some grief. You can get strict later in the development process, if needed.

Making every variable that is in a relationship optional solved all my errors. However, shouldn't the cascaded deleteRules make that unnecessary?

You can't set Relationship vars directly inside init function. Assign a value to them from outside
  let flight = Flight(company: company)
  flight.aircrafts = [aircraft]
  modelContext.insert(flight)

Also convert aircraft from "let" constant to var :
  @Model
  final class Flight {
  let company: Company
  var aircrafts: [Aircraft]

  init(company: Company) {
    self.company = company
    self.aircrafts = []
  }
}

PS: Change other models like this.

This actually solves the error. But do you know why that is? In other resources, relationship variables are assigned in the init, e.g. link

I guess this works for Xcode 16. I use Xcode 15 and can't set that in init function. So maybe this is the problem I guess

Hmm, it works for the other models, though. Maybe the many-to-many relationship makes it impossible to assign the relationship variable?
Also, conceptually what difference does it make to assign the variable after init but before inserting the instance into modelContext. Isn't it a bug?
And thank you btw for your solution! I am just curious and want to understand the underlying problem.
